# Browser.wait() in protractor for a specific id , when class changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Need to implement browser.wait() for a specific element. Need some help to get this done.

Scenario -> On click of a filter div , the hidden div appears. Need to wait till it is visible

Before Click -

```
<div id = "collapseGenericFilter" class="pannel-collapse collapse">
```

After Click -

```
<div id="collapseGenericFilter" class="pannel-collapse collapse in">
```

Is there any way to browser.wait on id, till a particular class selector visible.

I'am fixing this using

```
browser.wait(() => element(by.css('.panel-collapse.collapse.in')).isPresent(),
500,
'long wait');
```

Is this right?
I would have been happy if i found the dom element first by ID then followed by class some thing like this `element('GenericFilter').by.css('panel-collapse collapse in') etc.`

Note:- I'm very new to web technologies, So kindly ignore if it is a silly question, I'm still learning.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Chain function doesn't work for same element. It is designed to get
>   parent child element. For example ***div1 has another div with class name div2***. For this scenario we can use chain function ->> browser.element(by.id('div1)).element(by.css('.div2'))

***For your solution we can check element first by id then its class attribute***

```
    //first click on element  
    var genericFilter = browser.element(by.id('collapseGenericFilter')); 
    genericFilter.click(); 
    //It will wait for generic filter until it has exact class name 
    browser.driver.wait(function(){
         genericFilter.getAttribute('class').then(function(className){
                return className.indexOf('pannel-collapse collapse in') !== -1;
              },50000, 'Element not present ');
     },50000);
```